# How to list AD group membership for AD users using input list?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, membership

I'm fairly new PS user... Looking for some assistance with a powershell script to obtain list of security groups user is member of.

To describe what I need:

- I have input list (txt file) with many users (samaccountnames). Every name is on a new line.
- I need the script to search these names in AD - whole forest, not just one single domain
- output should look like "samaccountname" and list of groups this account is member of in one line, so I can sort it in excel

This is the script I have:

```
$users = Get-Content C:\users.txt

ForEach ($User in $users) {
  $getmembership = Get-ADUser $User.Users -Properties MemberOf | Select -ExpandProperty memberof
  $getmembership | Out-File -Append c:\membership.txt 
}
```

but it throws me an error:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again.
At line:4 char:28
+ $getmembership = Get-ADUser <<<<  $User.Users -Properties MemberOf | Select -ExpandProperty memberof
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Anyway, this script wouldn't search the whole forest.

Sample input list:

```
username1
username2
username3
username4... etc
```

Sample output list

```
username1;group1;group2;group3
username2;group1;group2;group3;group4... etc or something similar
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**First**: As it currently stands, the `$User` variable does not have a `.Users` property. In your code, `$User` simply represents one line (the "current" line in the foreach loop) from the text file.

```
$getmembership = Get-ADUser $User -Properties MemberOf | Select -ExpandProperty memberof
```

**Secondly**, I do not believe you can query an entire forest with one command. You will have to break it down into smaller chunks:

1. Query forest for list of domains
2. Call `Get-ADUser` for each domain (you may have to specify alternate credentials via the `-Credential` parameter

**Thirdly**, to get a list of groups that a user is a member of:

```
$User = Get-ADUser -Identity trevor -Properties *;
$GroupMembership = ($user.memberof | % { (Get-ADGroup $_).Name; }) -join ';';

# Result:
Orchestrator Users Group;ConfigMgr Administrators;Service Manager Admins;Domain Admins;Schema Admins
```

**Fourthly**: To get the final, desired string format, simply add the `$User.Name`, a semicolon, and the `$GroupMembership` string together:

```
$User.SamAccountName + ';' + $GroupMembership;
```

Comment: Good deal! Glad you found it helpful. Could you mark the answer as appropriate?

Answer (score 10):

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | select name
```

Got it from another answer but the script works magic. :)

Answer (score 0):

Or add "sort name" to list alphabetically

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | select name | sort name
```

Comment: I like this, but I'm unable to get it to work if i use  -ExpandProperty

Answer (score 0):

The below code will return username group membership using the samaccountname. You can modify it to get input from a file or change the query to get accounts with non expiring passwords etc

```
$location = "c:\temp\Peace2.txt"
$users = (get-aduser -filter *).samaccountname
$le = $users.length
for($i = 0; $i -lt $le; $i++){
  $output = (get-aduser $users[$i] | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership).name
  $users[$i] + " " + $output 
  $z =  $users[$i] + " " + $output 
  add-content $location $z
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Administrator Domain Users Administrators Schema Admins Enterprise Admins Domain Admins Group Policy Creator Owners
Guest Domain Guests Guests
krbtgt Domain Users Denied RODC Password Replication Group
Redacted Domain Users CompanyUsers Production
Redacted Domain Users CompanyUsers Production
Redacted Domain Users CompanyUsers Production
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything in one line:

```
get-aduser -filter * -Properties memberof | select name, @{ l="GroupMembership"; e={$_.memberof  -join ";"  } } | export-csv membership.csv
```