# Exporting all memberof values using Export-Csv with join

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm trying to pump out a list of users in a specific OU along with their group memberships to a CSV. I wanted a list of groups but I get "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection" My command is

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=Vendor Accounts,dc=mydomain,dc=com" -Properties * | Select ‘Name’,’DisplayName’,’SamAccountName’, @{Name=’MemberOf';Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.MemberOf))}}| export-csv c:\temp\citrix_vendors.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

I get all the other properties as expected, pretty columns and everything, but can't seem to get the multi-valued attribute to output the way I want. I'm running v4.

I looked at [How to list AD group membership for AD users using input list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238053/how-to-list-ad-group-membership-for-ad-users-using-input-list) and tried implementing a similar fix,

```
    $GroupMembership = ($user.memberof | % { (Get-ADGroup $_).Name; }) -join ';';
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=Vendor Accounts,dc=mydomain,dc=com" -Properties * 
    $user.Samaccountname + ',' + $GroupMembership | export-csv c:\scripts\citrix_vendors.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

but the output Changed from Columns with almost all the info I am grabbing to a single column titled "Length" with a number in each row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list AD group membership for AD users using input list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238053/how-to-list-ad-group-membership-for-ad-users-using-input-list)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.